# Can't link protobuf library

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Right now I have the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH set to (this is a directory that contains protobuf.pc):

```
C:\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\pkgconfig
```

And get this output when I try to look at pkg-config of protobuf:

```
PS C:\Users\Kevin Huang\Desktop\protobuf-cpp-3.13.0\protobuf-3.13.0\examples>pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf
-IC:/DEV/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include -LC:/DEV/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib -lprotobuf
```

But now when I try to compile by linking protobuf (using the above output), I get "cannot find -lprotobuf":

```
PS C:\Users\Kevin Huang\Desktop\protobuf-cpp-3.13.0\protobuf-3.13.0\examples> c++ -std=c++11 add_person.cc addressbook.pb.cc -o add_person_cpp -IC:/DEV/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include -LC:/DEV/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib -lprotobuf
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing here? This is my lib directory if that helps:

```
PS C:\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib> ls

    Directory: C:\DEV\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       11/20/2020   9:57 PM                pkgconfig
-a----       11/20/2020   9:56 PM         891436 libprotobuf-lite.lib
-a----       11/20/2020   9:57 PM        4016894 libprotobuf.lib
-a----       11/20/2020   9:57 PM         435276 libprotoc.lib
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to link a 32-bit compiler with a 64-bit library. Also note that g++ works with .a files, not .lib files.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to C++. I will try making these changes

Comment: Perhaps the architecture is okay, but the .lib thing still counts.